# which paradigms do not support for or while loops by nature?

Tags: paradigms

For what I know the Functional paradigm does not support For or While loops per se, but for performing loop tasks they use recursion instead. The question that I have is that if there is any other paradigm, apart of the imperative, that does not use loops, but emulate then by using other techniques.

Thanks

Comment: A J ( http://www.jsoftware.com ) or a Gura-lang ( gura-lang.org/ ) can manipulate collections. For example, in J you can define 2 list: `a =: 1 2 3` `b =: 10 100 100` and in order to multiply (a[1]*b[1], a[2]*b[2], a[3]*a[3]) you can just write `c =: a*b`. Ruby has `each` method but it's just the while/for loop without need for end value. Every mentioned languages have while/for loops but they might be not widely used (e.g. you use `each` instead of `for`), so that's why it's in comment. I can repost it later in a answer section if you wish.